# Cannot map drive from remote windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, networking

On my network I have a bunch of windows 7 machines. I have mapped folders from two of these machines on my local machine and it works fine. But now I have added a third windows 7 machine and for some reason I cannot map a drive/folder from that machine in explorer on my local machine. I can remote to the machine just fine using a remote desktop connection.

Could it be a firewall issues? Any suggestions on what I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if Network Visibility is turned on? Turn it on if its not already turned on. That way, you would be able to see other nodes on the network. Hope this helps.